# Create hashmap using swaggerhub

Tags: swagger-codegen, swaggerhub

My requirement is to create a dynamic set of fields so that they can be contained in a hashmap for further process of restful request. As suggested in [link](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/) :

```
  MyBean:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: true
```

The code that is generated is `equals`, `hashCode` & `toString` methods which are not populated with any type of fields.

```
public class MyBean {

  @Override
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash();
  }


  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class MyBean {\n");

    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }
```

Will the dynamic input will be contained ?
How can i create a hashmap for this purpose ?

Comment: Is your spec `openapi: 3.0.0` or `swagger: '2.0'`? The `true` value for `additionalProperties` is only supported in OpenAPI 3.0; OpenAPI 2.0 requires specifying a type for `additionalProperties`, e.g. `additionalProperties: <new line>  type: string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using :

```
MyBean:
    type: object
    additionalProperties:
      type: object
```

which is `HashMap<String, Object>` extended by my class. Found reference at [link](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1433).